# Is it possible to create a MongoDb user with multiple roles in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm attempting to add a method to create a new user in mongodb using java MongoClient. The only implementation I've found which works (from other threads) is:

```
 final MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("admin");
 final BasicDBObject createUserCommand = new BasicDBObject("createUser", "testUser").append("pwd", "password").append("roles",
                            Collections.singletonList(new BasicDBObject("role", "readWrite").append("db", "testDb")));
            db.runCommand(createUserCommand);
```

However, using Collections.singletonList only permits adding a single BasicDBObject to the roles list, and hence only a single role. I want to implement the equivalent of the shell command:

```
db.createUser( { user: "testUser",
                 pwd: "password",
                 roles: [ { role: "clusterAdmin", db: "admin" },
                          { role: "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
                          { role: "readWrite", db: "testDb" }
] } );
```

i.e. add multiple roles in the same create method call. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<BasicDBObject> roles = new ArrayList<>();
roles.add(new BasicDBObject("role", "clusterAdmin").append("db", "admin"));
roles.add(new BasicDBObject("role", "readAnyDatabase").append("db", "admin"));
roles.add(new BasicDBObject("role", "readWrite").append("db", "testDb"));
```

And this:

```
final BasicDBObject createUserCommand = new BasicDBObject("createUser", "testUser")
        .append("pwd", "password")
        .append("roles", roles);
db.runCommand(createUserCommand);
```